# How can I make my camera follow the player movement in a different position

Tags: unity, camera

Basically my camera follows the character rotation and position, although the position of it its pretty uncomfortable to use, this is what I needed:
[image]

But this is what the I get: 
[image]

I used a code that someone suggested me yesterday to use, I got a bit creative with it and changed some stuff to get other camera positions, but no matter how much I tweak the values the camera never gets the position that I need:

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.position = player.transform.position - (player.transform.up * -10) + (player.transform.forward * -15);
    transform.LookAt(player.transform);

}
```

I have no idea how I can make it show less of the player back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to elevate camera position upwards, add some arbitrary value you like as the `elevation` variable and you're good to go.

```
float elevation = 1.0f;//Value that you'd want to tweak
transform.LookAt(
    player.transform.position + player.transform.up * elevation, 
    player.transform.up
);
```

Also you'll probably need to decrease distance between camera and the player.

```
(player.transform.forward * -15)//It's here, tweak it
```

Comment: Theres only 1 problem, it says + cannot be applied to operands of type transform and vector 3 (sorry im kinda slow xd)

Comment: Found the problem :D I simply added position at the player.transform and now I dont have any error and your code worked, thank you so much Ocelot :3

Comment: @HugoSousa I've made an edit anyway.